# What cryptic aspect the following message has?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

My manager is sending some cryptic messages for fun. Here is the message:

> Mr.Black had a low value in the list followed by Mr.Brown. Sometimes, though the band in the dress they wore contained red, yellow and orange found a higher significance. Green of course was the middle one and the royals of blue and violet were naturally dearer. 
>   In spite of these, the purity of white was on the top, followed immediately by grey. 
>   In this whole representation, gold and silver had the least value. 
>   We are usually associated with Great Britain and we are of a very high standard.

As far as I know, it indirectly means something. I have only this information.

Will provide answer when my manager provides to us. Which could be probably at the end of today.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sounds to me like

> resistor colour-codes (also used for some other electronic components).

Mr.Black had a low value in the list followed by Mr.Brown.

> Black and brown signify digits 0 and 1 respectively.

Sometimes, though the band in the dress they wore contained red, yellow and orange found a higher significance.

> Red, yellow, orange are 2,3,4.

Green of course was the middle one and the royals of blue and violet were naturally dearer.

> Green, blue, violet are 5,6,7.

In spite of these, the purity of white was on the top, followed immediately by grey.

> Grey and white are 8,9.

In this whole representation, gold and silver had the least value.

> As well as signifying digits 0-9, the colours are used to denote powers of ten: $10^0$ to $10^9$. Gold and silver aren't used for digits but extend the exponents: gold is $10^{-1}$ and silver is $10^{-2}$.

We are usually associated with Great Britain and we are of a very high standard.

> Not sure quite what's going on here. There's a mnemonic for the colours that mentions Great Britain. (Mr_Green confirms that this is what he had in mind. "BB ROY Great Britain Very Good Wife".)

Comment: As a computer engineering student, when I saw Black and Brown in the paragraph, this was the first thing which jumped to mind. :-)

Comment: Me too, though I happen not to be a computer engineering student.

Comment: Aah, you beat me by umm $37-2=35$ minutes :P you're fast :)

Comment: I just happened to look at the right moment. (But my speed is very variable...)

Comment: The mnemonic is "BB ROY of Great Britain had a Very Good Wife who wore Gold and Silver Necklace"

Answer (score 0):

It's :

> [Colour codes for resistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code).

This

> Mr. **Black** had a low value in the list followed by Mr. **Brown**.  Sometimes, though the band in the dress they wore contained **red**, **yellow** and **orange** found a higher significance.
>  **Green** of course was the middle one and the royals of **blue** and **violet** were naturally dearer. In spite of these, the purity of **white** was on the top, followed immediately by **grey**. In this whole representation, **gold** and **silver** had the least value. We are usually associated with *Great Britain* and we are of a very high standard.
>
>  The colours were obvious, the (not so) Great Britain!

was a giveaway as

> I recognised [the user](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20026/mr-green) from the [Hinduism.SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/), I am sure he must have heard of this mnemonic in school/engineering. 
> **BB ROY, Great Britain Very Good Wife GSN** 
>  Yes that's how Physics is taught in schools :P

Comment: How is this answer different from Gareth's which was posted 30+ minutes ago?

Comment: I didn't see his answer, just saw it. Please my comment on his answer, I'll delete this if i find this obsolete.

Comment: Yes I heard about bbroy great Britain. Awesome :D

Comment: @Mr_Green The old teaching methods :)