# Cryptic aspect in the following riddle

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Here is the riddle:

> The law enforcer was leading the horse when he saw that the risk-taker besides him was also trying to support him. The owner of the country pub was in front of an efficient arid vehicle. The business man was given an important position in front of the leader. Irrespective of their profession, the doctor, the record keeper, animal hoof protector and the farmer also were in the front - showing a wonderful camaraderie. 
>   Their commitment was such that, though they could be considered a show at the start, but are most significant in the end.

What am I talking about here?

As in my [previous question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/36153/20026), this riddle also indirectly means something.

Very Big Hint

> It is related to Chess.

Comment: What's the question being asked? What are we supposed to find?

Comment: @Moose it is similar to this [question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/36153/20026)

Comment: I'm still unsure what you're asking. Are we supposed to decipher who these people are? What they're doing? Why they're doing it? I feel like you haven't given enough instruction as to what you (or your manager if it's him again) want us to do. In the other riddle you ask what cryptic aspect they all have, this one you don't ask anything

Comment: @Moose updated.

Comment: What *exactly* are we supposed to find? Decipher what the text is talking about / describing? If the point is that we're supposed to figure out what we're supposed to figure out, then add the [tag:enigmatic] tag.

Comment: @EngineerToast I gave the hint.

Comment: The hint doesn't tell us what we're supposed to figure out.

Comment: Am I suppose to say the answer? Tbh, i gave the closest hint. It is just that you might not have knowledge about this.

Comment: It would help to have each puzzle be self-contained, not rely on hints (or looking at other puzzles) for explanation, and explicitly ask a question or state a challenge. Unfortunately many puzzles are not good examples, but this puzzle could achieve it with minor edits.

Comment: @humn I don't think I am following you guys here. Tbh, this is a riddle which could be solved if one has knowledge about it. And also I don't see how self containing is different from giving hint. I am in chat room to discuss about this.

Comment: Who is the risktaker supporting: the law enforcer or the horse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This refers to:

> The pawns in a medieval chess set

The law enforcer was leading the horse

> The Policeman Pawn stands in front of the Knight

when he saw that the risk-taker besides him was also trying to support him.

> The Gambler pawn stands all the way to the left, besides the Policeman.

The owner of the country pub was in front of an efficient arid vehicle.

> The Innkeeper pawn stands in front of the Bishop, [which is called the camel in Mongolia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_chess#Mongolia)

The business man was given an important position in front of the leader.

> The Merchant pawn stands in front of the King.

Irrespective of their profession, the doctor, the record keeper, animal hoof protector and the farmer also were in the front - showing a wonderful camaraderie.

> The Doctor, the Clerk, the Blacksmith (who makes horseshoes), and the Farmer make up the other 4 pawns.

Their commitment was such that, though they could be considered a show at the start, but are most significant in the end.

> Pawns are in a line to begin a chess game, but oftentimes the winner of a game comes down to who has more pawns at the end, and they can also be promoted to more powerful pieces.

[Here's a description of each character.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawn_(chess)#History)

Comment: Could the arid vehicle be a [camel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_chess#Mongolia)?

Comment: @Neon612. Yes, that was it! Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

My answer is that this is a setup description of a final chess setup, we are to take the clues and place the characters back on the board as described. But I do believe that this is likened to the world stage political as derived through chess. The pawns have made it to the other side of the board and have bought themselves to be other pieces thus merchant pawns protecting, which has made those ruling the nature of the game stop warring and take notice and determine our future...Hillary Clinton and Donald Trump US Presidential Race...Final Answer